# Error reading JArray from JsonReader

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, json.net

The following method usually works, but sometimes it throws an exception. I'm not sure why, because it works most of the time. Maybe it is because I'm using a dollar sign to insert a variable into a string. Can someone tell me how I can do it differently in order to avoid the error?

Exception I get:

`Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Error reading JArray from JsonReader. Path '', line 0, position 0.'`

Method:

```
public RetrieveModels(string path)
{
    JArray json = JArray.Parse(File.ReadAllText($@"{path}"));
    [...]
}
```

The path is something like: `"C:\\Users\\ZAT\\source\\repos\\tool\\tool\\wwwroot\\processes.json"`

I create the path in the following Action method in the controller:

```
public IActionResult UploadFile(IFormFile file)
{
    if (file == null || file.Length == 0)
        return Content("file not selected");
    else
    {
        var path = Path.Combine(
                Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot",
                "processes.json");

        using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
        {
            file.CopyToAsync(stream);
        }
        RetrieveModels rm = new RetrieveModels(path);
        [...]
    }
}
```

It is also possible that it tries to parse the file, while it has yet to be created or is being created. Therefore, I tried putting `rm = new RetrieveModels(path);` below `file.CopyToAsync(stream);`, but that resulted in another exception saying that I cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

Comment: 1) Please show the full `ToString()` output of the exception including the exception type, message, traceback and inner exception (if any).  2) Try catching the exception and logging the first 200 or so characters of the file.  3) Incidentally, you will have better performance if you load directly from a stream, see https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ReadJson.htm and https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Performance.htm#MemoryUsage

Comment: Or maybe you could read directly from the stream returned by [`IFormFile.OpenReadStream()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iformfile.openreadstream?view=aspnetcore-2.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_IFormFile_OpenReadStream).  And possibly the wrong encoding is chosen at some point.  But beyond that there's not information in this question for us to guess the problem.

Comment: Are you sure the file has JSON in it, and it contains a JSON array (starts and ends with square brackets `[` and `]` )?  If the file is empty, that could explain the exception you are seeing.

Comment: @dbc Thanks for your help. I think I solved the problem. See my answer.

Comment: @BrianRogers Yes, I kept using the same json file and very rarely it just didn't work. I solved the problem by using `async` and `await`. I think the file wouldn't be fully created when I called the method. See my answer.

Comment: Ah, yes, if you are using an async method you have to await it.  If you don't then the result may not be ready by the time you try to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I solved the problem by using `async` and `await`:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(IFormFile file)
{
    if (file == null || file.Length == 0)
        return Content("file not selected");
    else
    {                
        var path = Path.Combine(
                Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot",
                "processes.json");

        using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
        {
            await file.CopyToAsync(stream);

        }
        RetrieveModels rm = rm = new RetrieveModels(path);
        [...]
    }           
}
```